# docker run -it bash -c 'Function from sourced file'

Tags: bash, ubuntu, docker

I have a file with couple of functions inside a docker container. I want to run:

```
docker run -it 06b68ae1c601 bash -c 'function1'
```

but the output is '/bin/bash: function1: command not found"

I have placed 'source /pathtofile' in /root/.bashrc, /root/.profile /etc/bash.bashrc but the file is still not sourced.

Also tried to run bash --login option, again command not found
The OS of the container is Ubuntu 14.04.

I dont want to run bash -c 'source /file; function1'.

Any idea where should i put the source command?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? Docker has a standalone isolated environment

Comment: I have couple of functions that i need to run inside a container, but i dont want to source the file every time i run them.

Comment: Can you turn them into a script and just run that instead?

Comment: No i cant, i need to keep them as functions.